# Webview very slow on Android using Ti SDK 6.0.2 and later

Tags: android, webview, titanium, appcelerator

Please, I would like to ask the Appcelerator/Titanium community for help. My app runs very well on Android using versions 5.X, 6.0.0 and 6.0.1 of the Titanium SDK. For some reason, starting with version 6.0.2, including 6.0.3, 6.0.4, and 6.1.X it was extremely slow. I upgraded Android SDK versions, including build-tools, as well as Node.js, but with no improvements. In addition, on iOS is everything fine. I know it's a very general question, but someone had performance issues on Android with these versions of Titanium SDK? Many thanks in advance.

Here is the informations about my environment:

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.11.6
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 8589934592

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.5.0
  npm Version                 = 2.15.9

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.14

Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 6.0.2.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/luna/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.GA
  Target Platform             = android
```

...

After many hours wasted I discovered that the problem is related with webviews (just on Android). Here is a single code to explain my problem:

```
//
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'white'
});

var htmlContent = '<html><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">';
htmlContent += '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />';
htmlContent += '</head><body This text is intended as a test for the webview usage examples:<br>';
htmlContent += 'Morbi a metus. Phasellus enim erat, vestibulum vel, aliquam a, posuere eu, velit. <br>Nullam sapien sem, ornare ac, nonummy non, lobortis a, enim. Nunc tincidunt ante vitae massa. <br>Duis ante orci, molestie vitae, vehicula venenatis, tincidunt ac, pede. <br>Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. <br>Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. <br>Donec quis nibh at felis congue commodo. <br>Etiam bibendum elit eget erat. Nam quis nulla. <br>Integer malesuada. In in enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. <br>Sed vel lectus. Donec odio urna, tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem. <br>Phasellus rhoncus. Aenean id metus id velit ullamcorper pulvinar. Vestibulum fermentum tortor id mi. <br>Pellentesque ipsum. Nulla non arcu lacinia neque faucibus fringilla. Nulla non lectus sed nisl molestie malesuada. <br>Proin in tellus sit amet nibh dignissim sagittis. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. Maecenas sollicitudin. <br>Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Etiam egestas wisi a erat.<br> Aenean placerat. In vulputate urna eu arcu. <br>Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi mattis felis at nunc. Duis viverra diam non';
htmlContent += 'Morbi a metus. Phasellus enim erat, vestibulum vel, aliquam a, posuere eu, velit. <br>Nullam sapien sem, ornare ac, nonummy non, lobortis a, enim. Nunc tincidunt ante vitae massa. <br>Duis ante orci, molestie vitae, vehicula venenatis, tincidunt ac, pede. <br>Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. <br>Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. <br>Donec quis nibh at felis congue commodo. <br>Etiam bibendum elit eget erat. Nam quis nulla. <br>Integer malesuada. In in enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. <br>Sed vel lectus. Donec odio urna, tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem. <br>Phasellus rhoncus. Aenean id metus id velit ullamcorper pulvinar. Vestibulum fermentum tortor id mi. <br>Pellentesque ipsum. Nulla non arcu lacinia neque faucibus fringilla. Nulla non lectus sed nisl molestie malesuada. <br>Proin in tellus sit amet nibh dignissim sagittis. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. Maecenas sollicitudin. <br>Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Etiam egestas wisi a erat.<br> Aenean placerat. In vulputate urna eu arcu. <br>Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi mattis felis at nunc. Duis viverra diam non';
htmlContent += '</body></html>';

var wvDemo = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    html:htmlContent,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    borderRadius: 1, // As recomended by Appcelerator docs, to force chromium (Android) rendering 
    scalesPageToFit:false
});

win.add(wvDemo);

win.open();
```

I create a single project by Studio using a classic project template and update de app.js code for this above. When I compile using SDK 6.0.1.GA or previous versions, the app run very well, fast. But, if I compile with 6.0.2.GA or late versions, the app run very very very slow and many messages like "[INFO]: Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." are generated.

Please, any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a additional information, when I compare the console log using the same app with SDK 6.0.1 and 6.0.2, when I run with 6.0.2 it show many many messages like: "[INFO] :   Choreographer: Skipped XX frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.". This message don't appear when I run with 6.0.1 or previous verions. Thanks!

Comment: I have a pretty big app which doesn't have any issues. Chances are quite big it is related to your code. A change in the SDK might actually decrease performance for whatever reason. Look at your code properly and make sure it doesn't do too much, try to identify the bottleneck in your code

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Rene.

Comment: It's very strange. My app use dozens of local html files and show its by webviews. A single vertical scroll on one of it generate many messages "[INFO] : Choreographer: Skipped XX frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread".  I don't have any explanation because the code in this point is very simple.

Comment: join us on http://tislack.org and share your code there, Perhaps we can debug it ;)

Comment: Many thanks, Rene. I update the post inserting a little example of issue. I appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: I have not noticed similar issues, though I use WebViews very sparingly. Do you see the same problems if you get rid of `backgroundColor`, `borderRadius`, and `scalePagesToFit` on the WebView? (I've never set any of those on my WebViews) Do you really need to use WebViews or could you use attributed strings in Ti.UI.Labels or other native views instead?

Comment: Thanks, Skypanther. Yes. If I remove this properties from webview, the results is the same, running very slowly. Unfortunately, I need to use webviews because my app show more then 2.000 formatted text (color, type, position, size, etc...) in local html files and many of then with content that are modified (by fire events) on the fly depending of some circumstances. In fact, I had many problems with webviews in the past (I use Ti since SDK 0.5.0) but since SDK 5.0.0 until 6.0.1 it was stable.

Comment: Additionally, this issues just happen on Android. With iOS it always worked perfectly.

Comment: Did you try to put `<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:largeHeap="true">` into your tiapp.xml?

Comment: Yes, Miga. Same result...

Comment: Guys, after many others tests and following the tip made by @miga above, I tried to change `android:hardwareAccelerated` to "false" and ... wow ... everything worked perfectly with a good performance, both on a app Test and on full app. I tested using SDK 6.0.2, 6.0.4, 6.1.0 and 6.1.2. There was many errors on 6.1.0 but using 6.1.2 everything worked OK. I'll do more tests but the firsts results make me more hopeful. Many thanks for you help!

Comment: After several tests using different versions of Android I discovered that the above solutions do not solve the problem using Android 7.X. After researching I discovered this [TIMOB-24540](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24540) problem which is exactly what I'm having. I have not got a solution yet.